# Need help on migrating J2EE project to Jboss 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, development-environment, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to migrate a J2EE project from Websphere to JBoss 6.1 & EJB 3.0.

I have successfully configured all the datasource, but when I launch the server, exceptions come up(see below):

### Do anybody know what happened and give me some suggestion, please? Thanks a lot.

```
08:56:54,715 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65)    JBAS018210: Register web context: /payment
08:56:54,716 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool --   65) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already   configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
08:56:54,716 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
08:56:54,763 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web]. [default-host].[/payment]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Initializing Spring  root WebApplicationContext
08:56:55,256 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/payment]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener:   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected   exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-  INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitio ns(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) [spring-beans- 3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDe finitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans- 3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDe finitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:348) [spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:269) [spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1197) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:204) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:204) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:136) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFileVisitor from [Module "deployment.payment.war:main"  from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
... 37 more
08:56:55,303 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config]  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.19-jbossorg-1 20131024-0833 for context '/payment'
08:56:56,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
08:56:58,181 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/payment/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
08:56:58,197 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /payment start, will stop it
08:56:58,197 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/payment]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
08:56:58,197 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool --  65) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default- host./payment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service  jboss.web.deployment.default-host./payment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException  in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
at  org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java: 96)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
at  org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService. java:60)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
... 6 more

08:56:58,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "payment.war" (runtime-name : "payment.war")
08:56:58,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)    JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./payment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./payment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

08:56:58,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
08:56:58,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
08:56:58,468 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in 16031ms - Started 496 of 559 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 59 services are  passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: From what I recollect you need to upgrade your spring framework, as there were some versions of it that detected that they were on (an older version of) JBoss and expect to be able to access the JBoss VFS, which no longer exists in newer JBoss versions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this file exists in your war file org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor ?
Can you check this file already provided in JBOSS and needs to be loaded from there.